# Algebra with two generators and relations

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have a $\mathbb{C}$-algebra defined by two generators $a$ and $b$ with the relations that $a^2 = b^2 = 1$.

I would like to know of ways to think about this algebra (commutative or not).

Comment: if you mean *commutative* algebra then you have just $\mathbb{C}\oplus\mathbb{C}\oplus\mathbb{C}\oplus\mathbb{C}$

Comment: @user8268: Thanks. I actually didn't mean commutative. I had gotten that part wrong.

Comment: @rschwieb: it is a ring isomorphism - it is obtained by setting $a=\pm1$, $b=\pm1$ in all possible (four) ways

Comment: @user8268 I still find your description of an isomorphism incomprehensible, but yeah, it's obviously a commutative semisimple ring, hence a product of $\mathbb{C}$'s. I went ahead and deleted my mistaken comment. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the algebra is noncommutative, ie $ab\neq ba$ then you have the group algebra over $\mathbb{C}$ of $\mathbb{Z}/(2) *\mathbb{Z}/(2)$, the free product of $\mathbb{Z}/(2)$s. If the algebra is commutative, ie $ab=ba$ then you have the group algebra over $\mathbb{C}$ of $\mathbb{Z}/(2)\times \mathbb{Z}/(2)$, the Klein 4-group.

Answer (score 1):

If you require $a$ and $b$ to commute, then it looks like a [graded algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graded_algebra) that one might see in algebraic geometry. It is a quotient of the [symmetric algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_algebra) of a two-dimensional vector space.

If you require $a$ and $b$ to anticommute ($ab=-ba$) then you are looking at a complex [Clifford algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clifford_algebra).

Comment: Thanks for this. It gives me something to think about.